# Two strings are anagrams of each other if and only if the sum and product of the characters of the strings are same. How?

Tags: string, algorithm, math, proof

I was reading an algorithmic problem at 
http://learn.hackerearth.com/question/314/finding-non-anagramic-strings-in-a-list/

I came across the following claim:

Two strings (of same size) are anagrams of each other if and only if the sum and product of the characters of the two strings are same (treat A => 1, B => 2, ..., Z => 26).

I tried to prove this but I failed. Can someone prove this claim?

Comment: Try doing it through induction

Comment: The claim is false. I found a counter example at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14739186/a-possible-algorithm-for-determining-whether-two-strings-are-anagrams-of-one-ano?rq=1

Comment: @AbhishekBansal The strings should be of the same size.

Comment: Actually that post deals with ASCII values though I won't be surprised if many such counter examples are found with this condition as well.

Comment: i'm not sure why your source would have thought it to be true.  Length, sum and product give you three constraints.  A length n string has n degrees of freedom, so we would expect to find lots of counter examples once n>3.  And in fact, your example, without the leading As, is a counter example of length 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The claim is really false. Following is a counter example.

- ABBI:  Sum = 14, Product = 36
- AAFF: Sum = 14, Product = 36

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the answer above this logic does not holds good. I would suggest to check if:

1. Length of string 1=String 2
2. if condition 1 is true then Sort String 1 and String 2 and compare them