# Anagram test by sum of characters

Tags: c, anagram

Can we solve anagram test puzzle by getting ascii value of each character in the string and then find sum of all characters , then calculate the same for other string and then compare two values(sum)?

Is it feasible?

Comment: No, different words could sum to the same value, for instance "ben" and "fan".

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) on how to ask a question.

Comment: It's simple to check if two strings are anagrams: Sort both and compare. `qsort` `strcmp`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A possible algorithm for determining whether two strings are anagrams of one another?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14739186/a-possible-algorithm-for-determining-whether-two-strings-are-anagrams-of-one-ano)

Comment: You can guarantee uniqueness by using a slightly similar approach of multiplying prime factors - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18781106/generate-same-unique-hash-code-for-all-anagrams/

Answer (score 6):

Of course not. Counterexample: `ac` vs `bb`.